# My Azure Function Intermittantly fails to read the connection string

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have an azure function that runs off of a queue trigger.  The repository has method to grab the connection string from the ConnectionStrings collection.

```
return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDataBase"].ToString();
```

This works great for the most part but I see intermittently that this returns a null exception error.
Is there a way I can make this more robust? 
Do azure functions sometimes fail to get the settings?
Should I store the setting in a different section?
I also want to say that this runs thousands of times a day but I see this popup about a 100 times. 
Runtime version: 1.0.12299.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add a private static string for the connection string.  Then only read from the configuration if it fails.  I then added a retry that paused half a second. This basically removed this from happening.

```
private static string connectionString = String.Empty;
    private string getConnectionString(int retryCount)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
        {
            if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyEntity"] != null)
            {
                connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyEntity"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                if (retryCount > 2)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Failed to Get Connection String From Application Settings");
                }
                retryCount++;
                getConnectionString(retryCount);
            }
        }
        return connectionString;
    }
```

I don't know if this perfect but it works.  I went from seeing this exception 30 times a day to none.

Answer (score 1):

Are you reading the configuration for every function call? You should consider reading it once (e.g. using a `Lazy<string>` and `static`) and reusing it for all function invocations.

Maybe there is a concurrency issue when multiple threads access the code. Putting a `lock` around the code could help as well. `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` should be tread-safe, but maybe it isn't in the V1 runtime.

A similar problem was posted [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/76b72a63-f89c-4b33-ae1c-0135552b5d19/configurationmanagerappsettings-returning-null-sometimes?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview), but this concerned app settings and not connection strings. I don't think using CloudConfigurationManager should be the correct solution.

You can also try putting the connection string into the app settings, unless you are using Entity Framework.

> Connection strings should only be used with a function app if you are using entity framework. For other scenarios use App Settings. [Click to learn more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#local-settings-file).
>   (via Azure Portal)

Not sure if this applies to the V1 runtime as well.

Comment: So what I did was add a private static string to hold the connection string.  when empty look it up from the connectionstring in the config.  If that fails pause 1/2 second and retry up to 3 times.  In the past 1 hour I have not seen this error popup.  I will keep you posted and add the code as the answer.

Comment: Might be a known issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1577 - Could be that they only fixed it for the V2 runtime.

Comment: Alex AIT your answer led me down the path of the solution below.  Thank you for your help